# Terraform Create a New EBS Snapshot on each Terraform apply

Tags: terraform, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use Terraform as part of my continuous deployment pipeline. I am using Terraform to create a snapshot of my production EBS volume (for backup purposes) prior to executing any other pipeline tasks.

I can get terraform to take the Snapshot, however the issue is Terraform will not create a new snapshot on each run. Instead it detects there is already an existing snapshot and does nothing.

For example.

Terraform Apply Execution 1 - Snapshot successfully taken.
Terraform Apply Execution 2 - No snapshot taken.

The code I am using for Terraform is provided below.

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "..."
  secret_key = "..."
  region     = "..."
}

resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "example_snapshot" {

  volume_id = "vol-xyz"

  tags = {
    Name = "continuous_deployment_backup"
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how I can force Terraform to create a new EBS snapshot each time it is run?

Comment: for anyone that is interested you can use the AWS CLI specifically the create-snapshot command to take a snapshot every time your pipeline runs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any repetitive and manual tasks if you are working on a continuous deployment pipeline, an option could be to run CloudWatch Events rules according to a schedule automating Amazon EBS Snapshots.
You can check it out [here in this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html) suggested by AWS in its CloudWatch Documentation.

You can use [Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager (Amazon DLM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html) to automate the creation, retention, and deletion of snapshots taken to back up your Amazon EBS volumes as well, always using terraform through the [`aws_dlm_lifecycle_policy` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dlm_lifecycle_policy.html) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, backing up on a schedule is a great idea and I actually already use the Amazon DLM to take backups of my production server on a daily basis. However, when I run my continuous deployment pipeline I would like to have a backup taken immediately prior to the pipeline execution, so if the pipeline fails for whatever reason I can restore the server to its exact state prior to the deployment operation and not the state that was last backed up on a schedule. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I understand, so you could use AWS CLI in your pipeline execution, let's see.